# How to read data with text line as a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data in the format of  (6 columns, text between "...." count as one column):

```
name kind number purenumber dew fin
John "['car' 'house' 'bicycle']" "[2 9 6]" 3 7 medium
Paul "['pool' 'gym' 'factory']" "[1 1 1]" 1 2 high
```

I need to load all the data between "........"  as a column and basic delimeter as a space for between columns. Could not find the correct load method with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/comp1/Desktop/cost_val.csv",  delimiter = '\t', sep=" ")
```

does not seem to be working, any way to quickly load this with pandas?

Comment: add quotechar = '"' argument into read_csv. That will make pandas to take all between quotes as single column.

Comment: also, make sure you have right delimiter, '\t' is tab, ' ' is space separator

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks! quotechar worked perfectly